# Understanding Python memory usage

Tags: python, memory

I have a slight issue with one of my Python scripts. It consumes a lot of resident memory.  It is a simple script of 240 rows. It sets up itself as RabbitMQ listener (pika), listens to requests and when it receives them, queries data from database (SQLALchemy, psycopg2) and returns it unprocessed as a response to the Rabbit message. It does not have threads or any other gimmicks.

In the same environment I run a couple of other, very similar scripts. I have another that does exactly the same, it just returns a bit different data (and is multi threaded as well as it provides two Rabbit connections and offers database write functionality as well through the second connection).

My problem script is at 700-800 mb, most of it resident, while the nicely running multi threaded script is 300mb, with 40mb resident component. Others operating in the same environment generally are 300mb/20-40mb.

I have added some debug functionality from resouce, objgraph and pympler. It does not seem to grow at all, so it does not seem to be leaking memory, and none of this debug information in my opinion adds up to the huge size of the running program.

```
Memory usage 784160

function                      12439    +12439
tuple                          5044     +5044
dict                           4723     +4723
weakref                        3057     +3057
list                           2209     +2209
type                           1605     +1605
wrapper_descriptor             1413     +1413
getset_descriptor              1329     +1329
builtin_function_or_method     1086     +1086
set                             844      +844

                                          types |   # objects |   total size
=============================================== | =========== | ============
                                           dict |        4723 |      4.76 MB
                                            str |       25520 |      3.32 MB
                                           code |       11511 |      1.41 MB
                                           type |        1547 |      1.35 MB
                                        unicode |         716 |    682.61 KB
                                          tuple |        5044 |    387.59 KB
                                        weakref |        3058 |    262.80 KB
                                           list |        2209 |    252.50 KB
                                            set |         844 |    237.47 KB
  <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.visitors.VisitableType |         239 |    211.07 KB
                              collections.deque |         208 |    126.75 KB
                             wrapper_descriptor |        1418 |    110.78 KB
                            function (__init__) |         866 |    101.48 KB
                              getset_descriptor |        1332 |     93.66 KB
                     builtin_function_or_method |        1086 |     76.36 KB
```

My question is, do these numbers look normal for a smallish script? If they do, where should I look next? Of course I can just add memory to the VM, but as all my other scripts are running just fine with the same dependencies (pika and sqlalchemy), I am just curious what goes wrong with the simplest one of them all.

Where should I look next?  The host is Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7.12.